# Any new SharePoint 2013 Development Certification after 70-488 Retirment

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer, certification

We are all aware that the 70-488 exam has been retired as of the 30th of September 2016. Does anyone know if any new certifications have been launched by Microsoft for SharePoint Developer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no other SharePoint Developer certification available. The only new certificate is [Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-339.aspx), but it's not a developer cert.